# How to create Bookmarks in the Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.12, bookmarks

I try to find a way to create a bookmarks in the QGIS Print Composer, so when i move the map with the pan option i will quickly return to the wanted frame of the Print Composer.

I search in the view menu in the Print Composer but didn't found any solution.

Comment: You can do something similar with the Atlas Generator: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html So you would draw your bookmarks as lines or polygons and have them hidden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible as there is already a feature request asking for this added functionality. However, it was asked over a year ago:

[Spatial bookmarks and the print composer](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/20279).

Comment: Indeed a crucial feature! Would be great to have an implementation very soon!

Comment: @hilpers - Agreed, can save a lot of headaches ;)

Comment: Now in the master branch: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/31547