# Create bookmark in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer

Three and a half years ago a user asked if it is possible to add bookmarks to the print composer in QGIS. The link is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207012/how-to-create-bookmarks-in-the-print-composer/207014). 
The answer was that someone posed a feature request for this feature.

I was wondering if this feature is now available? Perhabs it came with QGIS 3? I can't find it though but maybe I just don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the feature has been added, see
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/31547

[image]